# How to get rid of terminated error in Eclipse C++?

Tags: c++

```
void MenuFile(ifstream & Menu, string temp, string menu_strings[])
{
    int size = 0, i, j, loc;
    string placeholder;
    vector<string> placeholder_string;
    vector<int> Qnty; // move
    vector<double> Price; // move
    vector<string> itemName; // move
    bool MoreData = true;
    Menu.open("Menu.txt");
    if (Menu.fail())
    {
        cout << "File could not be found" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    while (MoreData == true)
    {
        if (Menu.eof())
        {
            MoreData = false;
        }
        else
        {
            getline(Menu, temp);
            menu_strings[size] = temp;
            size++;
        }

    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << menu_strings[i] << endl;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) // Converts File Quantities to Int
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            if (!isspace(menu_strings[i].at(j)))
            {
                placeholder.push_back(menu_strings[i].at(j));
            }
            else
            {
                placeholder_string.push_back(placeholder);
                placeholder.clear();
                break;
            }
        }
        cout << Qnty.at(i) << endl;
        Qnty.push_back(stoi(placeholder_string.at(i)));
    }
```

I am getting this error:

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)

I don't know what is wrong.  It either has something to do with the stoi or stod or a vector?

Comment: Do not tag C for C++ questions.

Comment: There is an incredible amount of things wrong with this code. But the error is dead-simple. You use an `.at()` function. That function throws an exception when you attempt an out-of-bounds access. Since you don't catch and handle the exception, your program terminates.

Comment: This also doesn't satisfy the requirements of a [mre]. You are making calls to code that isn't presented. People are less able to help when you don't provide an encapsulated example of the issue you're having.

Comment: if a function such as getline returns a value, do not ignore it

Comment: Run your program under a debugger and let it crash. You can then walk up the stack to see a) where it went wrong b) WHY it went wrong, with the exact inputs and values.